# Python imports when scripts are run from different folder (ancestor)

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I have a large repository with some fixed structure and I have extended it by some folders and python scripts to add extra functionality to it as a whole. The structure looks as follows:

- toplevelfolder

  - featureA

    - someModuleA.py
    - __ init __.py
  - featureB

    - someModuleB.py
    - __ init __.py
  - application
  - __ init __.py
  - app.py

Now `someModuleA.py` and `someModuleB.py` can be invoked via `app.py` but at the same time also have be able to be invoked directly, however this invocation must come from the toplevelfolder for the relative paths in the file to resolve correctly, i.e. via `python ./featureA/someModuleA.py`.

This all works well, but now I need some function definitions from `someModuleB` in `someModuleA` and hence I want to import this module. I have tried both absolute and relative imports, but both fail with different errors, the absolute import with

```
from toplevelfolder.featureA import someModuleA as A

# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toplevelfolder'
```

and the relative import with

```
from toplevelfolder.featureA import someModuleA as A

# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Now I can see that the relative import would cause problems when python is invoked from the `toplevelfolder`, as `..` would represent the latter's parent directory, rather than the parent directory of `featureA`. However, I cannot get a hold of the first error message, especially since `toplevelfolder` should not be a module but a package.

Is there another way to import in Python that I'm not aware of, if possibly without modifying PYTHONPATH or sys.path or something like that?

Comment: I would recommend calling your code as an _executable module_, for example: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m toplevelfolder.app` instead of `path/to/pythonX.Y toplevelfolder/app.py`.

Comment: @sinoroc that doesn't resolve the issue, and I am more interested in running `someModuleA` rather than `app` in the toplevelfolder.

Comment: Whether it's called `app` or `foo` or `bar` shouldn't matter. Of course you'll always have to adapt the answers given here to your own specific use case. Anyway... If you make sure to always use absolute imports, then it should work. This is assuming that the top level packages and modules are indeed in either the current working directory or installed in _site packages_.

Comment: Paste this above your import:`
```
import os,sys,inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir) 
```

Comment: instead of messing with `sys.path`, you should try to turn your project into an installable package: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: @sinoroc no obviously the name doesn't matter, but in the scenario I described that `app` resides in the toplevelfolder, whereas `someModuleA` resides in a subfolder, but still the python file within the folder (i.e. `someModuleA.py`) is run from toplevelfolder, which makes the scenario different than what your answer describes. 
Moreover, I think I clearly stated that absolute imports do not work in this particular scenario where `someModuleA.py` is run from the toplevelfolder rather than the featureA folder. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure on what the goal is here. My advice would be:

1. Identify clearly what you want your top level modules and packages to be.
2. Make all imports absolute.
3. Either:

   - make your project a real installable project, so that those top level modules and packages are installed in the environment's `site-packages` directory;
   - or make sure that the current working directory is the one containing the top level modules and packages.
4. Make sure to call your code via the *executable module or package* method instead of the *script* method, if the "*entry point*" you want to execute is part of a *package*

   - DO (*executable module or package*):

     - `path/to/pythonX.Y -m toplevelpackage.module`
     - `path/to/pythonX.Y -m toplevelpackage.subpackage` (assuming there is a `toplevelpackage/subpackage/__main__.py` file)
   - DON'T (*script* within a package):

     - <del>`path/to/pythonX.Y toplevelpackage/module.py`</del>
5. *(Optional)* Later on, once it all works well and everything is under control, you might decide to change some or all imports to relative. (If things are done right, I believe it could be possible to make it so that it is possible to call the executable modules from any level within the directory structure as the current working directory.)

**References:**

- Old reference, possibly outdated, but assuming I interpreted it right, it says that running *scripts* that live in a package is an anti pattern, and one should use `python -m package.module` instead: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/006793.html -- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3122/

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the top level directory. In featureB.someModuleB:

```
from featureA.someModuleA import two
```

[Sample directory.](https://github.com/Gerardwx/importexample)

Answer (score -1):

Try pasting this above your import:

```
import os,sys,inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir)
```

Then you should be able to import a file from the parent-folder.