# How to make my python sub-file see outside-file with import?

Tags: python-3.x, import, terminal, directory, python-packaging

My python file tree looks like below.

```
Temp - temp.py
     - Sub - see_out.py
```

temp.py

```
name = __name__
```

see_out.py

```
from Temp import temp
print(temp.name)
```

On pycharm, It works

> Temp.temp

But on the terminal at Temp directory, when I tried `python3 Sub/see_out.py`,

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "Temp/Sub/see_out.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Temp import temp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Temp'
```

Even I tried this in the Sub directory, result was the same as above.

How can I make it works and why pycharm works but not in terminal???

Comment: You should call it using the module notation and from the directory containing the top level modules and packages. Always. So for example: `python3 -m Temp.Sub.see_out`. Anything else is a waste of time.

Comment: In more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61698924

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python imports when scripts are run from different folder (ancestor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61680185/python-imports-when-scripts-are-run-from-different-folder-ancestor)