# How to define imports, __init__.py files and structure of an importable Python module

Tags: python, module, python-module, python-packaging

I have written a Python module (`AlloViz`) consisting on multiple classes.

```
AlloViz
├── Classes
│   ├── Data.py
│   ├── Edges.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── Pair.py
│   ├── Pkgs
│   │   ├── Corrplus.py
│   │   ├── Dynetan.py
│   │   ├── Getcontacts.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── MDTASK.py
│   │   ├── Pkgs.py
│   │   └── Pytraj.py
│   └── State.py
├── __init__.py
└── utils.py
```

When importing it, I would like to have available the classes from the `Classes` folder, and the classes defined in the `Pkgs` folder have to be used by State.py.

Either this way:

```py
import AlloViz
# I want to access the classes this way:
AlloViz.Data
AlloViz.Edges
AlloViz.Pair
AlloViz.State
```

or this way:

```py
from AlloViz import *
Data
Edges
Pair
State
```

Moreover, in the top-folder `__init__.py` there are some imports of modules included with Python (e.g., `os`, `sys`, `re`...) and other modules (e.g. `pandas`, `numpy`...) that I want to be available for all the rest of the files (e.g., using re.search in the class defined in `AlloViz/Classes/State.py`). The functions defined in `utils.py` should also be available for all the rest of the files.

I have almost lost my whole mind trying to figure out what to put in each `__init__.py` so that the imports are successful, I would greatly appreciate some guidance. If it would simplify things, I could make a single `Classes.py` and `Pkgs.py` files within the `AlloViz` directory, although they would be very long then. If I could take a look at some existing module that has a similar structure to check how the files look like I think I could figure it out, but I have not found any.

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61698924

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can use [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports). These take the following form:

1. `from .x import y` which means: in the current level of the package hierarchy, look for a module `x` and import the name `y` from it.
2. `from ..x import y` which means: go one level up in the package hierarchy, then look for a module `x` and import the name `y` from it.

Case (2) can traverse arbitrary levels of the package hierarchy by just prefixing it with more dots (one dot per level). So for the example the following

```py
from ...x.y import z
```

means: go up 2 levels in the hierarchy, then find package `x`, then import module `y` from `x` and finally import `z` from `y`.

For controlling what gets imported when using `from x import *` you can use [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

So in your specific case this would be:

```py
# AlloViz/__init__.py

from .Classes import Data, Edges, Pair, State

__all__ = ['Data', 'Edges', 'Pair', 'State']


# E.g. AlloViz/Classes/Pkgs/Corrplus.py

from ...utils import *
```

If you want any (third party) modules to be available in your own modules, then you can just import them (it will not cause any overhead beyond the first import since the modules are cached in [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules)). So just add `import os` or `import numpy` to all of the modules that need access to it.